# Arrayformula with dates before and after

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Here is what my spreadsheet looks like

[image: My Chart]

I enter recurring weekly payments details in G,H,I,J & K (Name,Amount,Day of week, Start Date, End Date respectively). This arrayformula:

```
=arrayformula(sumif(I2:I32,C2:C32,H2:H32))
```

shows the amount due (D), on the Date (A), whose day of the week (C) matches the one defined in I.

[Link to example to play with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoRQLQyxDaEedDljWDRHbHpRNG5TM0dCaUJBTlh2ekE&usp=sharing)

If I have something that will be due every Friday for example I put the name for the bill in G, the amount in H, and the day of the week # in I. When I do that column D shows amount that is due and repeats it on all the dates where column C (DOW#) match the provided value in column I.

**What I would like to do is**
make column D not add the amount if the date in A is before the date in column J or after the date in column K. It should work if neither J or K have values, if J has a value, if K has a value or if both J & K have a value.

All my attempts at figuring out how to compare the dates with gt (>) & lt (<) in the same arrayformula have failed.

Comment: Can you share a doc with us Lazfish? And show us the expected result.....sounds boring, but very helpful !!

Comment: I added the doc you wanted to see. @JacobJanTuinstra

Comment: greatly clarified my description in SE here and my expected output was all messed up. It should make sense now. @JacobJanTuinstra

Comment: I have to wait 24 hours to award this. Awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a custom function in Google Apps Script that takes all the criteria you want it to have (and more) in consideration.

### Code

```
function myPayments(paymentPlan, dateRange) {
  var output = [];  
  for(var i=0, iLen=dateRange.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var checkDate = new Date(dateRange[i]);
    var weekDay = checkDate.getDay()+1, sum=0;
    for(var j=0, jLen=paymentPlan.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      if(paymentPlan[j][1] == weekDay) {   
        if(paymentPlan[j][2] === "" && paymentPlan[j][3] === "") {
          sum += paymentPlan[j][0];
        } else if(paymentPlan[j][2] === "") {
          if(checkDate <= new Date(paymentPlan[j][3])) {
            sum += paymentPlan[j][0];
          }
        } else if(paymentPlan[j][3] === "") {
          if(checkDate >= new Date(paymentPlan[j][2])) {
            sum += paymentPlan[j][0];
          }
        } else if(paymentPlan[j][2] !== "" && paymentPlan[j][3] !== "") {
          if(checkDate >= new Date(paymentPlan[j][2]) && 
            checkDate <= new Date(paymentPlan[j][3])) {
            sum += paymentPlan[j][0];
          }
        } 
      }
    }
    if(sum == 0) {
      output.push([]);
    } else {
      output.push([sum]);
    }
  } 
  return output;
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Remarks

If you extend the `paymentPlan` range, to contain the rest of the data as presented in the PAYMENT PLAN sheet, then you will notice that overlapping payments will be summed.

Add the script under Tools>Script editor and press the save button (in your case it's already there).

### Example

I've added the solution in your example file.

Comment: Perfect! I think I will let the bounty end so I can award more. I don't really have experience with this bounty stuff so if you think that won't work I will accept now.